# Import Excel sheet data into SQL Table using SSIS programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to implement a solution for importing Excel sheet data into a SQL table in *SSIS programmatically* using ***C#***, through **Edit Script** task.

Unfortunately, i do not find any simple example on how to achieve similar solution online.

Below is the code which i tried in Edit Script window and it is throwing me the below error.

```
  public void Main()
        {
            ADODB.Connection conn=new ADODB.Connection();

            string strSQL;
            object lngRecsAff;

            conn.Open(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Engagements\QCRT\SSIS\InputFolder\Order.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0","","",0);
            strSQL = @"SELECT * INTO [ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=IN45216580W1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=[Northwind]].[dbo].[Order_Test1] FROM [1$]";
            conn.Execute(strSQL,out lngRecsAff,0);


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

**Error Message:**

Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Could not find installable ISAM.
   at ADODB.ConnectionClass.Open(String ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)
   at ST_2d2b7b209a00481087e0c1720214c207.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

I am very new to SSIS and What am i doing wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this programmatically? There are far simpler ways if achieving this sort of a connection in SSIS without resorting to scrpt

Comment: If you have an application, which takes an Excel file and loads its data into Sql Server, use Microsoft.Ace.Oledb provider to query excel workbook and use SqlClient to load this data into table on the DB server. There are plenty of examples online

Comment: Which is the solution ? any source code?